# Powershell - Add a column value to a variable

Tags: csv, powershell

I have to do a powershell script with a csv file and I need to set a value for a variable which is an entire column like this an ONLY this column:

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk3Xq.png)

I have already do this :

```
$fichierCSV = "C:\file.csv"
$listetel = Import-Csv $fichierCSV -Delimiter "t"
```

Do anybody know how to set a value in a variable to contains this column ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :

I've done that :

```
 $listetel = Import-Csv $fichierCSV -Delimiter "t"  | select Noannuaire, NewPropertyName
Write-Host $listetel
```

And when i launch, this return me that:

```
@{Noannuaire=; NewPropertyName=} @{Noannuaire=; NewPropertyName=} @{Noannuaire=; NewPropertyName=}
```

Do anybody have a solution? :/

EDIT2: I've do this:

```
$listetel = Import-Csv $fichierCSV -Delimiter "t"  | select Noannuaire, NewPropertyName
$listetel |ft
```

But now the window show me this:

[csv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLcnD.png)

I don't know if it's a problem with my csv file, anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only values (without name of the property) try:

`$listetel | select -ExpandProperty Noannuaire`

If you want to add extra column (property) try:

`$listetel | select Noannuaire, NewPropertyName`

EDIT:
You get `@{Noannuaire=; NewPropertyName=} @{Noannuaire=; NewPropertyName=}...` because this is what you are asking with `Write-Host $listetel` -> Try just `$listetel` or `$listetel | ft` (without Write-Host) :)

EDIT2:
Let's do the following:

1. `` $listetel = Import-Csv $fichierCSV -Delimiter "`t" ``

Note the `` -Delimiter "`t" `` ! Not as you wrote `-Delimiter "t"`

2. Check if data is properly imported => type this to show results:

`$listetel | select Noannuaire | ft -AutoSize`

And you should see Name `Noannuaire` and your values below. If the values are still empty, name `Noannuaire` is not recognized as column name. You should check that (probably is not in first row or you posted wrong delimiter).

3. If this is what you are looking for, save it with new column (property):

`$selected = $listetel | select Noannuaire, NewPropertyName`

If you find this as a solution to your problem, please mark this answer as best answer so we can finish this question. Cheers!

Comment: It don't works, i see a error when i lunch my script :/

Comment: @Pieo update your question with the error then, we can't guess what it says on your screen

Comment: @badsamaritan First, thanks for your help! I have another problem, the screen show me nothing when i do that, i will edit my post to show you that.

Comment: Try this. If this isn't working, you made a mistake somewhere or should change your CSV ;)

Comment: @badsamaritan THANK YOU for your help! :) It's work! you are my savior of the day

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad to hear that :)